# Change services.AddScoped<UnitOfWork>(); to services.AddTransient(); because of no dispose method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, service-locator

In the video of course CQRS in Practice.

[image]

In the Startup.cs code, it has the following code.

```
public void ConfiureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    service.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<UnitOfWork>();
}
```

However, the code needs to be to `services.AddTransient();` because there is no dispose method for `UnitOfWork`? Why `UnitOfWork.dispose()` is required for `AddScoped`?

Comment: Who told you there needed to be a `Dispose`?

Comment: Does `AddTransient` have dispose method?

Comment: There is no need for the `Dispose` method in case of `AddScoped`.

Comment: @mjwills It's in a course "CQRS in Practice". I updated the question to attach the screenshot.

Comment: @user1672994, I've updated the question. It's about the dispose of `UnitOfWork`

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of an object (scoped, transient, singleton), is a wholly separate issue from whether or not the object implements IDisposable.

It is sometimes the case that objects that implement IDisposable are used in Dependency Injection (often because they're external dependencies that have unmanaged resources), but it's not always that way.

`AddScoped`, in the context of ASP.NET Core, means that for the lifetime of an ASP.NET request, that same object will be used.

`AddTransient`, in the context of ASP.NET Core, means that every object instantiation -- even during the same HTTP request, will use a new instance of that object.

For your particular problem -- the Unit of Work issue, you're going to want to make sure whatever database you're using is OK with multiple readers and writers before switching to `Transient`, the reason being if you're using `AddTransient`, then if you make multiple calls to the database, you're going to open new transactions and (possibly) connections for each call; and there are databases that do not like this very much (Postgres being a shining example).

The lingo we use to talk about that is the [`Multiple Active Result Sets`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&ei=xDa4Xd--DOKHggfvuKS4CQ&q=Multiple+Active+Result+Sets+Postgres&oq=Multiple+Active+Result+Sets+Postgres&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.7096.8022..8195...0.2..0.262.1433.0j8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0.lO0FYZZuT08&ved=0ahUKEwjfsK2NwsHlAhXig-AKHW8cCZcQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) issue, and each database handles it differently.

Comment: So would be more approprieted to register an UnitOfWork as Scoped? (i.e in .net Core + Sql Server)

Comment: @Marcoscdoni If you're using EF, the DbContext is already a UnitOfWork; and so having a Unit of Work abstraction over the DbContext is at best pointless. If you're running an ASP.NET web application, then Scoped is generally the right approach (scoped means 1 instance per request).  If you're running a Console application, you may want Transient or Scoped depending on what sort of threading model you have set up.